# Insert Text Field Name or ID as Value in MySQL Column

Tags: php, mysql, html

In my extremely limited development experience, when I submit a form, usually the name or ID of an input value corresponds with a column in a MySQL table and the name of both the name/ID and column are known.  But I have what amounts to an order form where I have a number input and assign the name/ID a unique ID from a table that has all the available items.  How can I submit the input name or ID along with its value when I am dynamically populating the name/ID?

Example:

```
<?php '<input type="number" name="'.$row['itemID'].'" id="'.$row['itemID'].'">';?>
```

Table Structure I would like to insert into has the following columns:

1. itemID
2. quantity

The itemID would be posted from the name of the input field and the quantity would be the value of the input field as entered by the user.

Any guidance is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What problem are you encountering? Are you not able to submit or are you not able to get the values from $_POST on the server?

Comment: You need a value attribute for your inputs. Also input is a self-closing tag (as far as I know).

Comment: @Ethan22: I don't know how to get the value of itemID from $_POST.  I can get the value the user enters no problem.

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis: I don't need a value attribute.  The user enters that value.  You're right about the self-closing tag, however.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `foreach($_POST as $id => $value)` loop and get the key, but then you'd never be able to use any other input values besides the ones named with an item ID.

**SOLUTION**: With the following method, you can use any other inputs you want inside the form:

```
<input type="number" name="products[<?php echo $row['itemID']; ?>]" id="<?php echo $row['itemID']; ?>" />
```

Now in your php, you can access `$_POST` and it will look like this:

```
[
   'products' => [
       '123' => 4,
       '456' => 1,
       ...
   ]
]
```

Now you can loop through `$_POST['products']` in a foreach without worrying about other input values.

```
foreach($_POST['products'] as $id => $num_purchases)
{
    //stuff
}
```

Comment: "but then you'd never be able to use any other input values besides the ones named with an item ID."  You mean like if I want to insert a username in the row or something?

Comment: With this solution you don't have to worry about other inputs, use whichever and as many as you want. I was just pointing out that a simple loop through $_POST could work if id and quantity was the ONLY input in your form.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks!  I think the key for my problem was making an array out of itemID.  I stink at arrays...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have understood you correctly but may be you need a hidden input array to store all names from $_POST;

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="allNames[]" value="'.$row['itemID'].'">';
```

Later in your code after post:

```
$all_names = $_POST['allNames'];
foreach($all_names as $key => $value) {
    echo $_POST[$value];    //Take the user input
}
```

Comment: How is the user supposed to enter a value?  I need the id of the item (itemID) and the quantity, which is the value the user would enter.

Comment: You can take the value from here: '<input type="number" name="'.$row['itemID'].'" id="'.$row['itemID'].'" value="">';